# TinyMCE color_map with classes

Tags: tinymce, tailwind-css, wysiwyg, tinymce-5

I would like to ask you, if is there a way how to setup TinyMCE color pallete with classes.
I've found a solution with predefined hex colors, but it's not what I want:

```
    color_map: [
        '#1f478f', 'Primary',
        '#DF271F', 'Secondary',
        '#000000', 'Black',
        '#ffffff', 'White'
    ],
```

When I apply color, it looks like this:

```
<p><span style="color: #df271f;">Hello, World!</span></p>
```

I am using Tailwind CSS and I define my colors with text-primary-500, text-secondary-400 etc.
So my goal is to push those classes to tinyMCE, no matter what colors are defined with them and get results similar to this:

```
<p class="text-primary-500">Hello, World!</p>
```

or

```
<p><span class="text-primary-500">Hello, World!<span></p>
```

So whenever I change class `text-xxx-xxx`, it changes in TinyMCE as well.
Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ghodc12/). Thank you guys for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do isn't possible with the `forecolor` or `backcolor` options.

The values provided will be copied to the style attribute, so are hardcoded in the content. (Even if you provide a css variable to set the color, you will end up with a hardcoded RGB-value).

If you do want to apply a class, so that you can can change the styling of the colors afterwards, you sadly need to do this with `style_formats`.

For example:

```js
style_formats: [
  {title: 'Primary text', inline: 'span', classes: "text-primary"},
  ...
]
```

Will generate a `<span class="text-primary"></span>` in tinymce's output.

You could still generate these options with Tailwind's `resolveConfig` as outlined in p.loeffler's answer.

I've edited your JSFiddle to show that this works: https://jsfiddle.net/87zsgpwv/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use predefined TailwindCSS colors as tinyMCE colors.

As you want to configure your colors in JS, you will need your Tailwind colors as JSON rather than class names. To get them you need to implement this code:

```
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";
import tailwindConfig from "path/to/tailwind.config.js";

var colors = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig).theme.colors;
```

More on that [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script).

You can then use the JS Variables `colors.primary`, `colors.secondary` etc. in your tinyMCE config:

```
color_map: [
        colors.primary, 'Primary',
        ...
],
```

Now, when you change your Tailwind Configuration, the colors in tinyMCE will change accordingly.

Comment: I don't think this actually solves the OPs question. It the Tailwind config changes, content that is created/edited will use the new colors, but all existing content will still use the old colors.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible using TinyMCE 6 forecolor and hilitecolor formats.

First, you need to create a map of hex colors to tailwind colors:

```js
const tailwindColorMap = {
  '#4B5563': 'gray-600', // Hex letters need to be uppercase for this to work
  '#4338CA': 'indigo-700',
  // ...
}
```

Quicker way by importing tailwind colors:

```js
import tailwindColors from 'tailwindcss/colors'

function colorMapForTailwindColors(colorArray = []) {
  let colors = {}

  colorArray.forEach((color) => {
    for (let key in tailwindColors[color]) {
      colors[tailwindColors[color][key].toUpperCase()] = `${color}-${key}`
    }
  })

  return colors
}

const tailwindColorMap = colorMapForTailwindColors([
  'gray',
  'red',
  'amber',
  'yellow',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'indigo',
])
```

Next, update the `color_map` so these colors show up in the TinyMCE color palette:

```js
color_map: Object.keys(tailwindColorMap)
  .map(function (key) {
    return [key, tailwindColorMap[key]]
  })
  .flat()
```

Finally, set the forecolor and hilitecolor formats to use the tailwind class names:

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea', // change this value according to your HTML

  color_map: Object.keys(tailwindColorMap)
    .map(function (key) {
      return [key, tailwindColorMap[key]]
    })
    .flat(),

  formats: {
    forecolor: {
      inline: 'span',
      attributes: {
        class: (value) => `text-${tailwindColorMap[value.value]}`,
      },
      links: true,
      remove_similar: true,
      clear_child_styles: true,
    },
    hilitecolor: {
      inline: 'span',
      attributes: {
        class: (value) => `bg-${tailwindColorMap[value.value]}`,
      },
      links: true,
      remove_similar: true,
      clear_child_styles: true,
    },
  }
})
```

Now when you set the text color of an element, the value from the color picker will be passed to the callback (eg. `#4B5563`), and that value corresponds to a key in the `tailwindColorMap`, which returns the tailwind class name.